# Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android

Is the problem here from php script or maybe from my android code?
This is my phpScript :

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM events  ORDER BY Eid DESC";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

$data = array();
$json = array();
if($result->num_rows >0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $data[] = array(
        'Title' => $row["Title"],
        'Date' => $row["Date"],
        'Time' => $row["Time"],
        'Location' => $row["Location"],
        'image_url' => $row["image_url"]); 
        }
  }
  header('Content-Type:application/json');
 $json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
print_r($data);
exit;
?>
```

Output in my browser:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Pediatrics 1st Bekaa
            [Date] => 2018-01-31
            [Time] => 04:30:00
            [Location] => Bekaa
            [image_url] => http://www.khazaal.tech/DoctorMobileApp/images/2.PNG
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Can this Doctor Change your life in 10 mins or less?
            [Date] => 2018-02-27
            [Time] => 08:30:00
            [Location] => Biel
            [image_url] => http://www.khazaal.tech/DoctorMobileApp/images/3.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Basic & Advanced Ericksonian Hypnosis � NFNLP Certified
            [Date] => 2018-09-27
            [Time] => 06:00:00
            [Location] =>  Zalka - Beirut
            [image_url] => http://www.khazaal.tech/DoctorMobileApp/images/1.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Lebanon Medical Expo 2018
            [Date] => 2018-01-31
            [Time] => 10:30:00
            [Location] => Beirut
            [image_url] => http://www.khazaal.tech/DoctorMobileApp/images/2.PNG
        )

)
```

This is my EventsActivity.kt (Kotlin) calling to list all records

```
package com.example.sandra.drapp

import java.util.ArrayList
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.VolleyError
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog.d
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest



class EventsActivity : Activity() {

    // Log tag
    private val TAG = EventsActivity::class.java.simpleName

    // Events  url
    private var url = "http://www.khazaal.tech/DoctorMobileApp/Events.php"
    private var pDialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    private var events = ArrayList<Events>()
    private var listView: ListView? = null
    private var adapter: CustomListAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events)
        setTitle("EVENTS")



                listView = findViewById(R.id.list) as ListView
                adapter = CustomListAdapter(this, events)
                listView!!.setAdapter(adapter)
                pDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                // Showing progress dialog before making http request
                pDialog!!.setMessage("Loading...")
                pDialog!!.show()

                // Creating volley request obj




        val EventsReq = JsonArrayRequest(url, object: Response.Listener<JSONArray> {

                            override fun onResponse(response:JSONArray) {

                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString())
                                hidePDialog()
                                // Parsing json
                                for (i in 0 until response.length())
                                {
                                    try
                                    {

                                        var obj = response.getJSONObject(i)
                                        val events = Events()
                                        events.setTitle(obj.getString("Title"))
                                        events.setDate(obj.getInt("Date"))
                                        events.setTime(obj.getInt("Time"))
                                        events.setLocation(obj.getString("Location"))
                                        events.setImage_url(obj.getString("image_url"))

                                    }

                                    catch (e:JSONException) {
                                        e.printStackTrace()
                                    }
                                }
                                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        }, object: Response.ErrorListener {

                    override fun onErrorResponse(error:VolleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        d(TAG,"Error: ", error.getLocalizedMessage())
                        hidePDialog()
                    }

                })
                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(EventsReq)
            }
            override fun onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy()
                hidePDialog()
            }

          private fun showDialog() {
            if (!pDialog!!.isShowing())
                 pDialog!!.show()
            }
            private fun hidePDialog() {
                if (pDialog!!.isShowing())
                    pDialog!!.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

I used json_encode but its not using correct json format..
In my app getting org.json.JSONException:value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be convertedto JSONArray  And in my json part browser getting SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I need some help plz Im a begginer

Comment: you need to change your output in jSon format

Comment: In your posted code, you send both JSON and non-JSON data as part of your response: `echo $json;print_r($data);`. This will break any consumer expecting JSON data.

Comment: When i removed print_r($data); it gives me blank page

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in your phpScript

```
print_r($data);
```

Comment: When i removed print_r($data); it gives me blank page

Answer (score 0):

you have several errors in your code.

**1.** in your PHP code remove `print_r($data);` you only need to echo `$json`.

`print_r()` will print the content of the array which is not JSON formatted.

change it to

```
<?php
  require_once 'connect.php';
  $sql="SELECT * FROM events  ORDER BY Eid DESC";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);

  $data = array();
  if($result->num_rows >0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $data[] = array(
    'Title' => $row["Title"],
    'Date' => $row["Date"],
    'Time' => $row["Time"],
    'Location' => $row["Location"],
    'image_url' => $row["image_url"]); 
    }
 }
  header('Content-Type:application/json');
  echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  exit;
?>
```

**2.** you are expecting date and time to be String not int. so change

```
     events.setDate(obj.getInt("Date"))
     events.setTime(obj.getInt("Time"))
```

to

```
    events.setDate(obj.getString("Date"))
    events.setTime(obj.getString("Time"))
```

Comment: 1.When i removed print_r($data); it gives me blank page

Comment: 2.I already have date and time in my database as int, Is'nt wrong to put them as string here?

Comment: I am not talking about how you put them. from your JSON output it's clear that `2018-09-27` is not an int. so this will give you an error while mapping to int. reformate your date. Am I right?

Comment: okaayy.. ur right.. I will edit this, but when i remove print_r($data) it gives me blank page on my browser and on my app "end of input at character 0 of"

Comment: @BishoyAbed I copied ur edited code but it also gave me a blank page..do you know why blank page? I'm thinking if php script from online host restrict json encode..does that make sense?or it doesnt matters